# AWS. Connecting to sql server Express using aws lambda written in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm trying to insert a simple record in my SQL server express database which is installed manually on a EC2 instance (Not RDS). However, after publishing to AWS lambda and try to invoke, I get this error:

```
{
  "errorType": "SqlException",
  "errorMessage": "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)",
    "at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)",
    "at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)",
    "at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)",
    "at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)",
    "at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)",
    "at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)",
    "at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)",
    "at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)",
    "at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)",
    "at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()",
    "at AWSDB.Function.FunctionHandler(String input, ILambdaContext context)",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )"
  ]
}
```

also I made a simple seperate .net core console application and added records to the database successfully.

Below is the code I use:

```
var connectionString = @"Server=tcp:[serverIP]\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Initial Catalog=apilambda; User ID=[user];Password=[password]";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into accounts (Fname,Lname,number)              values (@fname,@lname,@number)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", des.name.firstName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", des.name.lastName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", des.number.ToString());
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    context.Logger.LogLine("****end order ****");               
}
```

Comment: Is your lambda running within a VPC?  AWS runs your lambdas in a VPC by default, which would restrict your ability to connect to other services.

Comment: Hi Mark, Yes my lambda function is running in my AWS default VPC and so is the EC2 instance and also I'm allowing all traffic in it's security group